# How to delete existed bytes of the DocumentFile Android Studio - Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created a `DocumentFile` from `Intent.getData()`. `DocumentFile.canWrite()` returns `true`. But I can not clear the existed bytes of the `DocumentFile`. Help me

I have tried all methods,

```
String s = "";
outputstream.write("");
```

None of these methods worked.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the existing document, then writing your new one?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"?   Truncate the file to 0 length?  Overwrite the content?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks You , Truncate method working and fixed my problem. But now I am Facing another problem.

Comment: I am facing a new problem, I want to load html file in webview But the webview says Net_Error_Access_Denaid. But when I checked file.canRead it returns true. I am facing this problem in Android 13 only.

Comment: do not mix your questions...create a post for each question

Comment: My problem is solved. Thank all of you for trying to help beginners at no cost. Thanks from my heart